# FSM implementation using single always block in Verilog?

Tags: fpga, verilog, state-machines, synchronous

So while looking up for material on implementing high level state machines in Verilog I came upon this:[image] I am also trying to implement a high level FSM in Verilog that has a number of nested conditional (if) statements and many inputs. Overall the design I am trying to implement is a synchronous design where the inputs and outputs are also available on clock edges. So my question is is there any pitfall in designing an FSM like this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach in the example is a perfectly reasonable way of designing state machines. It's also the approach I tend to stick with for all of my designs, including some pretty darn large state machines in big systems.

The thing to remember about this approach though is that everything happens with a one-cycle latency from the state. To explain what I mean, lets look at the example you gave:

```
...
S0: begin
    L <= 0;
    D <= 0;
    state <= S1;
end
...
```

When we are in state `S0`, the `L`, `D`, and `state` registers all get updated. However because it is a clocked process, the values don't change immediately when we enter `S0`. Instead they change the clock cycle *afterward*. This means that taking this example, `L` and `D` will go to 0 when we *enter* state `S1`. Any logic that uses the `state` register should be aware of this when doing any calculations. It's also something to bear in mind when analysing simulation output.

Beyond that there are practical upshots to this design.

All of the outputs are registered, which means anything using them down the line doesn't have to contend with a cloud of combinational logic. This is as opposed to state machines in which the outputs are asynchronously dependent on the state machine registers which will result in a large combinational cloud that can cause timing problems in high speed designs. That's where the 1 cycle latency in this approach comes from.

I find it much clearer to follow because you have all of the logic in one place, following in a high level state by state layout. This is unlike ones which split the design into two always blocks - an asynchronous one for logic, and a synchronous one for the next state.

**TL;DR** Basically you can use this design approach very successfully, as long as you remember and can cope with the 1 cycle latency.

Comment: Thank you for the very elaborate answer. Conventionally it has been taught to use separate `always` blocks for combinational and sequential logic but I have observed it becomes cumbersome for high level designs.

Comment: Also is there any issue if I implement my nested loops like this: `if(a==1)  if(b==1)  if(!c)  state <= S1;  else  state <= S0 ;`.

Comment: @Candy you can use nested if statements, yes. Just remember thought that the more nested layers you have, the more complex the inferred logic becomes. In any case for that example, you could simply do: `if ((a==1) && (b==1) && (!c)) state <= S1; else state <= S0;`

Comment: One thing I should note: resets. Some things need to be reset, some things don't. For example, if you have  a data register that has a separate data valid flag, you may be able to simplify the design by only resetting the flag. This can be very important if you're trying to infer particular hard blocks. However, this is difficult to split out in a single always block state machine.

Comment: @alex.forencich that's true. Generally what I'll do in that case is have to have the data generated separately with control signals coming from the state machine. It can get a bit finicky accounting for the latency though.